# Report Services sort column chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have a report containing a regular column chart that groups on product (column A) and the chart column values are the sums of the cost (column B). By default these are sorted alphabetically on the product string. I want it to sort the column values by default and then I would like to provide and option for the user to be able to switch between product name and column value. How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Sort By` report parameter of `Text` type.

1. Set the `Available Values` and `Default Values` as follows :-

[image]
[image]

2. In the Column Chart, add an expression in the `Sorting` property of `Category Group`

[image]

Assuming you have the column values column as `ColumnValue` and Product Name column as `ProductName` then the expression should be :-

`=iif(Parameters!SortBy.Value = "ColumnValues",Sum(Fields!ColumnValue.Value),Fields!ProductName.Value)`

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer. Nice way of introducing an interactive sort, I like it :) Although I cant get the sorting on the Values instead of the Category Groups to work. When I choose sort on Values it displays the data in a different order compared to when it sorts on the Category Group, but not sorted on Values. Any idea what the error could be? Again thank you for your help.

Comment: post your expression and the name of the columns in report

Comment: Hi and sorry for late response. I've been away for a while. The columns are "Cost" and "Language" and the expression is "=iif(Parameters!OrderBy.Value = "Cost",Sum(Fields!AmountNumber.Value),Fields!Language.Value)"

Comment: Oh and if the "Language" option is selected I want to sort in ascending order (A-Z) but if the "Cost" option is selected I want it to sort in descending order (Z-A). Thanks!