# Reporting Service months in x-axis

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, bar-chart, ssrs-2012

I have a bar chart that shows values for each month in the year. Therefor my bar chart has 12 values on the x-axis. Now they show the numbers 1-12 but I would like instead of numbers to show the name of each month "Jan"-"Dec" or "January"-"December". How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: How are the values stored?  Are you plotting against a set of Dates in a year, or against a set of numbers from 1 to 12?

Comment: I extract the year to one column and the month to another column and then I use month as a "Category group" and year as a "Series group"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the month number try set label x-axis to this:

Or you can create a calculated field in the dataset and set it to the above expression then use that field in the x-axis label.

**EDIT:** I reproduced a possible scenario of your chart.

This is a chart with **month number** in x-axis, according to your description it is what you are getting now:

[image]

The easiest way to get the month name is using a **calculated field**:

Right click on dataset, go to Fields tab, click add button and type the name to the field in this case `MonthName`
[image]

In Field Source click on right side button `Fx` for set the expression
and add the following expression:

```
=Switch(
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=1,"January",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=2,"February",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=3,"March",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=4,"April",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=5,"May",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=6,"June",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=7,"July",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=8,"August",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=9,"September",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=10,"October",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=11,"November",
Fields!MonthNumber.Value=12,"December",
)
```

Click Ok, and update your chart to use the MonthName field (not the MonthNumber)

[image]

Right click on `MonthName` in **Category Groups Properties**.

[image]

In sorting tab you should sort by `MonthNumber`, in my case is `[Numero Mes]` as follows:
[image]

After this you should get the following chart preview.
[image]

Let me know if this was helpful.

Comment: Hi. Sorry for a late response. I have been away for a while. So I'm trying your solution now but I can't quite seem to get it to work. For the x-axis I choose Axis type: Scalar (numbers/dates), Minimum = 0, Maximum = 12, Interval = your expression, Interval type = Months. The result is one value on the x-axis (1/1/1990). What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: @Rebam1, check the update I did on my answer. Don't change Axis type for my example it is not necessary.

Comment: That was an awesome answer with a great explanation. Thank you so much! I'm gonna go ahead and give you the right answer for that as it does indeed answer my question. But I got a little side problem after implementing your solution, and it is that the sorting got messed up. I did what you wrote with the sorting but it didn't help. Before the bar chart was sorted but now it is sort of sporadically showing the bars. Any idea as to what could be causing this? Thanks!

Comment: If your previous question was solved I recommend you to create a new question with the new problem in order to your question get the visibility of more users. Could you tell me how the x-axis is being sorted? Maybe: April, August, February? or what are you getting? or your problem is with the bars but not with axis?

Comment: The x-axis is sorted in the order "April, August, December, February, January, July, June, March, November, October, September". Thanks

Comment: That's cause you are sorting by `MonthName` not by `MonthNumber`. Right click on Category Groups item (in my case MonthName), go to properties and select the `Sorting` tab. You have to change the column to order by `MonthNumber` and select the order type desc or asc. Check the sorting part in my answer.

Comment: Ok now I feel stupid, but once again you are here to save me. You're the man. Thanks!!!

Comment: If you feel like it I have another pending question here :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247631/report-services-sort-column-chart/32255646#32255646